# C# Overloaded method invocation with Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I wonder what is the reason for the invocation of the method that prints "double in derived". I didn't find any clue for it in the C# specification.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Print(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int in base");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Print(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int in derived");
    }
    public void Print(double x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("double in derived");
    }
}



B bb = new B();
bb.Print(2);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I you can decipher the rules of 7.4.2.2 and 7.4.2.3, you're probably cleverer than me, but it will be there somewhere.

Comment: @spender, It might be in there, but It's written poorly :).

Comment: Waiting for Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: This has been answered.
See this thread : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821620/different-behaviour-of-method-overloading-in-c-sharp

Comment: Marking as dupe. Skeet's answer to the question above is good.

Comment: @cvraman, that example is slightly different, even if it gives the same result. In that case the integer literal is also of type object (a widening cast is occurring). However in the example given above an implicit cast is taking place (from int to double.)

Comment: Does somebody know why this does not happen if you declare the Print method like this? `public new void Print(int x)` (hide the base `Print` method). The same happens if you just declare it as `public void Print(int x)` and removing the base class. Then the int method gets called. Seems to come from the inheritance.

Comment: @ebeeb see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from the C# spec (7.5.3 Overload resolution):

> the set of candidates for a method invocation **does not include methods marked override** (§7.4), and **methods in a base class are not candidates if** any method in a derived class is applicable (§7.6.5.1).

In your example, the *overriden* `Print(int x)` is not a candidate and `Print(double x)` is applicable, so it is picked without a need to consider the methods in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler looks at methods which are freshly-declared in the most derived class (based on the compile-time type of the expression) and sees if any are applicable. If they are, it uses the "best" one available.

See the answer to this question :

[Different behaviour of method overloading in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821620/different-behaviour-of-method-overloading-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please quote and include a link to the original answer. Thank you.

Comment: Added a link to the above answer, where the quote was taken from